# Can't upload file inside an asp:formview inside an asp:UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, formview

This is the aspx file:-

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalProgress" runat="server" TargetControlID="panelUpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="panelUpdateProgress" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:FormView ID="formviewReg" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="false" OnItemUpdating="formviewReg_ItemUpdating">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnupdatepersonal" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnupdatepersonal_Click" ValidationGroup="g1">Update</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtneditpersonal" runat="server" OnClick="lbtneditpersonal_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
//some html controls
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What I've tried is trying to access the file in FileUpload1 by placing it inside the EditItemTemplate block then placing it outside it i.e. outside the formview and then outside the updatepanel. But in no way does the FileUpload1.HasFile returns true. Is there any way I can work around this process. I want to access Fileupload1's file on clicking lbtnupdatepersonal so this is what I am using in aspx.cs file:-

```
protected void lbtnupdatepersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)//returns false
        {
            ViewState["imageext"] = uploadFile1(FileUpload1.PostedFile, "StudentPhoto/");
        }
        formviewReg.UpdateItem(false);

    }
```

Comment: send my .aspvb file code

Comment: file upload code

Answer (score 0):

The FileUpload control will not work inside an UpdatePanel control for uploading files using Asynchronous postback. This is because file uploading and file manipulations are restricted by default in the client side for security reasons. Hence it is not possible to upload files using asynchronous postback in UpdatePanel.

I found this website which states that it provides a workaround for this problem:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482800/FileplusUploadplusinplusUpdateplusPanel